# ASP.NET parent page update with JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

here is my problem:
I have a ASP.NET appl. In the appl, there is a page (page A) that brings up a second page (page B) Page b is a simple form that fills a dataGrid that is located in Page A. I have tryed many approaches (IDisposable, creating methods for it...) but it does not give me the correct functioning. I have been looking into it for quit a while now and I am pretty sure the right way to do it is by using javaScript, but I am not that expert in that technology. I wonder if someone could point me to a solution (whether is JavaScript or not) or point me to an article that could make me understand the preblem better.

Many thanks for your help guys!!!!!
Cheers

Comment: If you post some CODE, you will likely get a lot more answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure this is what you are asking, but you can refresh the parent page with javascript like this

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

and then

```
window.close();
```

to close your second window